# Cygwin nested groups

Tags: domain, cygwin

I've got cygwin(latest release) running on a 2012 Windows server and having problems with adding domain grups. I succesfully dealt with domain users adding them to /etc/passwd as needed. For domain groups however, I created a local group and mapped all the local groups with mkgroup -l > /etc/group. Inside of that group I put my domain account. looking in the /etc/group file I see my group +sshUsers however, when trying to ssh to the server I keep being asked for password so something's wrong. Not sure how to check what format cygwin sshd expects my account to by typed in knowing it's case sensitive. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: $mkgroup -d | grep -i "group_name" >> /etc/group    does the job at least partly as after adding the group I can't access the ssh server under a member of the group credentials for some reason